# RESTFUL web service v Message queue when using Scatter Gatherer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, microservices

Say I have a scatter gather setup like this:

```
1) Web app
2) RabbitMQ
3) Scatter gather API 1
4) Scatter gather API 2
5) Scatter gather API x
```

Say each scatter gather (and any new ones added in future) need to supply an image/update an image to the web app, so that when the web app displays the results on screen it also displays the image.  What is the best way to do this?

1) RESTFUL call from each API to web app adding/updating an image where necessary
2) Use message queue to send the image

I believe option two is best because I am using a microservices architecture.  However, this would mean that the image could be processed by the web app after requests are made (if competiting consumers are used).  Therefore the image could be missing from the webpage?

The problem with option 1 is the scatter gatherer apis are tightly coupled with the web app.

What is the appropriate way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer:** There is no right way to do this.

**The long answer:** Because there's no right way to do this, there a danger that any answer I give you will be an opinion. Rather than do that, I'm going to help clarify the ramifications of each option you've proposed.

**First thing to note:** Unless there is already an image available at the time of the HTTP request, then your HTTP response will not be able to include an image. This means that your front-end will need to be updated after the HTTP request/response cycle has concluded. There are two ways to do this: polling via AJAX requests, or pushing via sockets.

The advantage of polling is that it is probably easier to integrate into an existing web app. The advantage of pushing the image to the client via sockets is that the client won't need to spam your server with polling requests.

**Second thing to note:** Reporting back the image from the scatter/gather workers could happen either via an HTTP endpoint, or via the message queue, as you suggest.

The advantage of the HTTP endpoint is that it would likely be simpler to setup. The advantage of the message queue is that the worker would not have to wait for the the HTTP response (which could take a while if you're writing a large image file to disk) before moving on to the next job.

**One more thing to note:** If you choose to use an HTTP endpoint to create/update the images, it is possible that multiple scatter/gather workers will be trying to do this at the same time. You'll need to handle this to prevent multiple workers from trying to write to the same file at the same time. You could handle this by using a mutex to lock the file while one process is writing to it. If you choose to use a message queue, you'll have several options for dealing with this: you could use a mutex, or you could use a FIFO queue that guarantees the order of execution, or you could limit the number of workers on the queue to one, to prevent concurrency.

I do have experience with a similar system. My team and I chose to use a message queue. It worked well for us, given our constraints. But, ultimately, you'll need to decide which will work better for you given your constraints.

**EDIT**

The constraints we considered in choosing a message queue over HTTP included:

- Not wanting to add private endpoints to a public facing web app
- Not wanting to hold up a worker to wait on an HTTP request/response
- Not wanting to make synchronous that which was asynchronous

There may have been other reasons. Those are the ones I remember off the top of my head.

Comment: May I ask what your constraints were (see last paragraph).

Comment: Updated answer with constraints.

Comment: Thanks.  Before I mark the answer; do you use polling or events when using the scatter gather pattern? and do you use console apps or web apis for each consumer?

Comment: Technically, we're not doing scatter/gather. But, our architecture is similar. We send out hundreds of individual jobs at once, letting our workers tackle them in parallel. Each worker utilizes web APIs to do their work. Then they report back via a queue.

Comment: Thanks.  Do they use events or polling?

Comment: Whoops! Sorry, forgot about that. Everything is event driven.

Comment: Thanks.  What would you do if the receiver could not process the upload of the image? (send an error event back to the sender)? This would mean the picture would be missing on the web client even i.e. polling would not find it? Is this acceptable in your opinion? Can it be classed as eventual consistency? Thanks again.  +1.